# Create a binary flag to see if a column contains certain terms between two tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

table 1:

```
terms
apple
banana
candy
```

table 2:

```
search_terms
apple cake
good apple cake recipe
nothing special
banana pudding
bananapudding
candybar
```

The expected result table:

```
search_terms      | flag 
apple cake        | yes
good apple recipe | yes
nothing special   | no
banana pudding    | yes
bananapudding     | no
candybar          | no
```

I'm trying not to use cross join as there are many terms. My working code:

```
with targeted_terms as (select distinct terms from t1)
select distinct 
search_terms, 
REGEXP_CONTAINS(search_terms, CONCAT(r'(?i)(\b', t1.terms, r'\b)')) as flag
from t2
cross join t1
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but are you aware [you can create search indices on BigQuery tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/search-index#create_a_search_index) and use a function called [SEARCH](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/search) to find terms? Depending on your actual problem, might this be be more effective than a homebrew solution?

Comment: Hi @PaddyAlton Thanks for your comment. I learned a new function today! I wasn't aware of the `SEARCH` function which queries the table information. Yet, I need to do some calculations based on the joined records, this search function cannot help me get there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid a cross join, how about concatenating your search terms into a single (potentially very long...) regex? It can use `|` to search for multiple different possibilities in one go.

Something like this might work:

```sql
    SELECT
        search_terms,
        REGEXP_CONTAINS(
          search_terms,
          SELECT STRING_AGG(terms, '|') FROM t1
        ) AS flag,
      FROM
        t2
```

Comment: Hi @Paddy Thanks for your input!!!! One main problem I encounter is that, if a term is "apple cake", the search term "apple" will be marked as true. In my case, it should be a false as I want the match of the full term

Comment: hahahaha it seems that I got the answer for myself - `SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(r'(?i)(\b', terms, r'\b)'), '|') FROM t1`

Comment: I think your given example is a little confusing in that case - my understanding was that you wanted to look at the string 'apple cake' and indicate a positive match because it contains the term 'apple'? However, if it were the other way around you still shouldn't have the problem you describe: the string 'apple' doesn't contain the term 'apple cake', so shouldn't match.